# Reduce a pandas interval dataframe to a table of 12-month x 24-hour aggregate values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with utility meter interval-data, which consists of a timestamp (typically 1-hour or 15-minute increments) and an energy consumption value (in kW or kWh). I would like to **quickly** convert a pandas dataframe with individual readings to an annual summary with the average values, maximum values, and counts on a per-month, per-hour basis.

The format of the annual summary will be a 12-month x 24-hour table (288 individual cells), where each cell is either the average, maximum, or count of all values from that particular month and hour.

**To keep things simple, let's just look at calculating the count.** (From suggestions, I can infer performing similar calculations for averages and maximums.)

I have tried a brute-force approach of filtering timestamps by month and hour (a loop of 288 values) and tabulating the counts into a matrix. However, this approach seems very slow as I perform these calculations on even 20 meters. I am curious if there is a quicker way to achieve this leveraging pandas/numpy.

The following is an example of how the interval-data is formatted.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["start"] = pd.date_range(start=datetime(2018, 1, 1), end=datetime(2018, 12, 31, 23), freq='900S')
df["value"] = 1
df.set_index("start", inplace=True)
```

I'm currently performing a calculation along the following lines:

```
for month in range(1, 13):
    for hour in range(0, 24):
        count = df.query("index.dt.month == {} and index.dt.hour == {}".format(month, hour)).count()
```

An output for counts for this data would look like the following. (A side note: sometimes data is not complete, which this table can help identify.)

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12
0   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
1   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
2   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
3   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
4   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
5   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
6   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
7   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
8   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
9   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
10  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
11  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
12  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
13  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
14  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
15  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
16  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
17  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
18  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
19  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
20  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
21  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
22  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
23  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), then if necessary, use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to remove axis names as per desired output.

```
df_new = (pd.crosstab(df.index.hour, df.index.month)
          .rename_axis(None)
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

[output]

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12
0   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
1   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
2   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
3   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
4   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
5   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
6   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
7   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
8   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
9   124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
10  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
11  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
12  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
13  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
14  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
15  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
16  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
17  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
18  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
19  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
20  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
21  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
22  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
23  124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
```

Comment: So is cross_tab doing a count by default (if you don't pass aggfunc?)

Comment: @AndyHayden yes exactly

Comment: " computes a frequency table of the factors unless an array of values and an aggregation function are passed" ah nice.

Comment: Works like a charm! Just for reference, I was able to compute "average" and "maximum" with`pd.crosstab(df.index.hour, df.index.month, df.values, aggfunc=aggfunc)` where `aggfunc` is `np.mean` and `np.max` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a groupby then unstack:

```
In [11]: res = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.hour])["value"].sum().unstack(0, fill_value=0)

In [12]: res.columns.name = "month"  # or None to suppress

In [13]: res.index.name = "hour"  # or None to suppress

In [14]: res
Out[44]:
month   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12
hour
0      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
1      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
2      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
3      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
4      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
5      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
6      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
7      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
8      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
9      124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
10     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
11     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
12     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
13     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
14     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
15     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
16     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
17     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
18     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
19     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
20     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
21     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
22     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
23     124  112  124  120  124  120  124  124  120  124  120  124
```

Note: I get different values, I get ~120 since 4 times per hour times  number of  days in each month (some months being longer than others)...

Comment: Nice catch! I fixed the question to reflect the correct expected-output.